# Rules to create file level @package

Tags: php, apigen

My code looks like this:

```
/**
 * @package Test
 */
require_once('foo.php');

/**
 * Main class
 */
class Test{
}

/**
 * Generic exception
 */
class Test_Excepcion extends Exception{
}
```

I want the first docblock to be a file level block, but ApiGen seems to link it to the require statement and my classes show up in the "None" namespace. It gets fixed if I do e.g. this:

```
/**
 * @package Test
 */
//
require_once('foo.php');
```

Is this the intended behaviour? Do I need to add a bogus comment after the file level block? What are the precise rules?

Answer (score 1):

The @package tag is not necessarily a file-level block. You can specify the @package tag for each class in your file. Like this:

```
/**
 * Main class
 * @package Test
 */
class Test{}
```